# Could you tell me what is function(el)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, canjs

I have some code:

```
hideLoadMask : function(response,config){
    //Once the response is processed for a particular request it will be removed from the processing array
    this.loadMaskRequestQueue =
            this.loadMaskRequestQueue.filter(function (el) {
                return el.requestID !== response.requestID;
        });
}
```

Here in `el` contains the data like:

`loadingText: "Loading...Please wait."`
`requestID: 1`

When I call `hideLoadMask()`, I pass `response="Loading...Please wait."`

Could you tell me what is `function(el)`, how my response parameter's value became as a field to `el`, what is `requestID`.

Please clarify my doubts.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 4):

It's an inline anonymous function definition that serves as a callback to the `.filter()` method.

The `.filter()` method takes a callback that it calls to carry out it's operation.  You can either define a named function elsewhere and then pass that function's name or you can define the callback function inline with this type of syntax.

The `el` in the `function(el)` signifies that the `.filter()` method will call the callback with at least argument (the array element currently being filtered) and this is the argument that the callback wishes to use.  If you check the documentation for `.filter()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you will see that it actually passes three arguments to the callback, but this particular callback only cares to use the first argument so that's the only one it bothers to declare.

Comment: the this.loadMaskRequestQueue is created just now, how the filter method became as a member of loadMaskRequestQueue ??  plz clarify

Comment: @NageswaraRao.K - `this.loadMaskRequestQueue` must already be an array before this method is called.  The assignment is just creating a new filtered array and then assigning it back to the same `this.loadMaskRequestQueue` so that `this.loadMaskRequestQueue` then contains the filtered version of the array after this method is run.  It's analogous to something like this `str = str.slice(1);`.

Comment: how 'el' contains the data like loadingText: "Loading...Please wait." requestID: 1. I heard 'el' created when a button clicked or an event by html element is fired and that el contains the data of the corresponding html element. but here is a different senario. could you explain this.

Comment: @NageswaraRao.K - You haven't shown enough code for us to have any idea what is in `this.loadMaskRequestQueue` so I have no idea what `el` is.  It appears to be some sort of object that has some properties.  FYI, this site is not designed for you to continue to ask more and more questions in comments.  You ask one question in your main question.  We attempt to answer that.  You can ask us to clarify our answer, but if you have new questions, you should probably post a new question and make sure you include enough information in that new question for people to understand what you're asking.